# Set operation A\B in Common Lisp

Tags: set, lisp, common-lisp

I just started learning Common Lisp 2 days ago, so please excuse spaghetti code and non-understanding.

My problem is the following: I want to write a function that performs the set-
operation A\B, where A and B sets that are not empty. They are represented by two lists.
So far I came up with this:

```
(defun myDifference (a b)

    (if (null a)
        (return-from myDifference) ;when a hits NIL, get outta the whole function
    )
    (if (not(member (car a) b)) ; if the first element of A ist not in B, add it to a list (which later should be the return)
        (cons (car a) '())
    )
    (myDifference (cdr a) b) ; proceed with the remaining elements of A, until (null a) hits

)
```

I tried it with: 
`(myDifference '( 1 2 3) '(1 5 6))`

But the output is NIL, whichever lists I try it on.
I suspect the problem occurs in quitting the function.

Comment: `cons` has no side effect. In your code its result immediately goes into the Lisp nirvana.

Comment: So cons should be avioded under this circumstance? How should I get around the cons?

Comment: maybe you want to use the value. If not you can delete the whole second if expression, since it does nothing useful if you compute a value and return it into the trash immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 3 expressions in your `my-difference` body. The first returns `nil` if `(null a)`

The second computes either `(list a)` or `(list)`, then discards that value.

The third recurses with a changed to `(cdr a)`.

It's clear that this **has to return `nil`** since the last one eventuelly recurses with `a` becoming `nil` and the recursion then returns `nil` since that is the default value when you don't supply a value. A better approach would be to make it one expression like this:

```
(defun my-difference (a b)
  (if (null a)
      a
      (if (not (member (car a) b))
          (cons (car a) (my-difference (cdr a) b))
          (my-difference (cdr a) b))))
```

The third part of `if` is the `else` part and as you see we nest to get somthing similar to  `if-elseif-else` of other languages.  This can be written flatter with `cond`:

```
(defun my-difference (a b)
  (cond ((null a) a)
        ((not (member (car a) b))
         (cons (car a) (my-difference (cdr a) b)))
        (t (my-difference (cdr a) b))))
```